# How can I redirect a url of a domain to a specific directory

Tags: iis, dns, nav

I have a clients website on their domain https://nav.clientdomain.com:8080/DynamicsNAV100/WebClient

Is there anyway to configure this to go to the above url with just https://nav.clientdomain.com:8080/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the HTTP redirect module.

If you don't have it installed, go to Add Roles and Features > Server Roles > Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Common HTTP Features > HTTP Redirection

Now inside the IIS Manager, select your website and under the IIS config, look for the HTTP Redirect module.

Just enable the checkbox "Redirect requests to this destination" and type `DynamicsNAV100/WebClient`.

Comment: This is almost almost correctly answers my problem.  I am now getting a redirect too many times issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what could be causing that. Yesterday I was trying something similar but also with URL Rewrite. You can also install that module (it's from microsoft) and add  a rule that matches `^$` and then redirects to your subdirectory.